# Bitwise AND operation program execution issue

Tags: c, bitwise-and, bit-banding

Below is a program in which I am trying to reset a particular bit of a hexadecimal number. The bit location, number of bits to reset, and hexadecimal value all are user inputs.

#### Header file

```
#pragma once

int bit0(int i,unsigned int RegA,unsigned int RegB,int s[]);
```

#### C file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "targetver.h"
#include "bit.h"

int bit0(int i,unsigned int RegA,unsigned int RegB,int s[])
{
    unsigned int j=0;
    unsigned int K=0;
    unsigned int L=0;

    printf("\nThe bit is at s[0] is %x\n", s[0]);   

    for (j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
        K = (1 << s[j]);
        L = ~K;
        RegB = RegA & ~L;
        printf("\nThe bit is %x\n", RegB);

        if (RegB | 0)
        {
            RegB = RegB & ~ (1 << s[j]);
        }
        else
        {
            RegB;
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe new reset bit is %x\n", RegB);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

#### main file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "targetver.h"
#include "bit.h"

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int s[35]={0};
    unsigned int RegA = 0;
    unsigned int RegB = 0;

    printf("Enter the hexa decimal value to be reset ");
    scanf_s("%x", &RegA);
    printf("Entered hexa decimal value is %x ", RegA);

    printf("\nHow many decimal places needs to be reset (0-31) ?");
    scanf_s("%d", &i);

    printf("Enter the decimal places that needs to be reset ");

    for (j=0; j<i; j++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &s[j]);
    }

    ///// check the entered hex value on those decimals places as bit 0 or bit 1

    bit0(i,RegA,RegB,s);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling and running executing the above code using Visual Studio.

The problem is in the C file, on the `RegB = RegA & ~L;` line.  The AND operation seems not to be taking place because I am getting 0 as the `RegB` value.

#### Program input:

Enter the hexadecimal value to be reset : 0100 1111

Entered hexadecimal value is : 0100 1111

How many decimal places needs to be reset (0-31): 1

Enter the decimal places that needs to be reset : 1

Comment: Facetiously, 01001111 is an *octal* literal.

Comment: @Bathsheba Which looks like binary, which is supposed to be hexadecimal. I call it a *total mess*.

Comment: What's with `#include`ing `"iostream"`?  This appears to be an attempt to include a C++ header into a C program.  The program already includes `stdio.h`, as it should, so I don't see any point at all.

Comment: There are no decimal places in a hex number.

Comment: Anyway, I think VS has an integrated debugger.  Have you considered using it?

Comment: And clarification: "hexadecimal" is one word.  My edit fixes that (among other things) in your prose, but on principle I have not modified anything about your code except insignificant whitespace.

Comment: Check the values of RegA and ~L to be sure. Here's a quickie(gives me RegA=0x4F and ~L=0x2):     
    L = ~K;
    printf("RegA: %X, ~L: %X", RegA, ~L);
    RegB = RegA & ~L;

Comment: @kundrata I checked for the register values by having a break point in most of the places.
i = 0x00000001
j = 0x00000000
k = 0x00000002
L = 0xfffffffd
RegA = 0x01001111
RegB = 0x00000000
s = 0x00effa94

what I dont understand is why is the value of L is 0x00000002 and not 0x00000010.

Comment: 0x0002 = 0b0010. It's the same value: 2 in hexa means 10 in binary.

Comment: @kundrata I am aware that 0x0002 is 0b0010. But why are that other values are represented in hexadecimal like for example L = 0xfffffffd but not the value of K. why I dont see K as 0X00000010

Comment: When you shift(<<) the computer always shifts bits. It works in binary, not hexa. We just use hexa representation to make numbers easier to read. That's why they're called bitwise operations: shift, and/or etc.

Comment: When you shift to the left, it's equivalent to multiplying by 2(to the power of how many places you shift). 0x01 << 1 = 0x02(1 * 2). And  0x01 << 4 = 0x10(1 * 16, 16 is 2 to the power 4). Hope you get it now.

Answer (score 0):

Well *of course* you get 0, but that's because the `&` operations you have written *are* (all) being performed.  Here's the relevant section of your code:

```
    K = (1 << s[j]);
    L = ~K;
    RegB = RegA & ~L;
    printf("\nThe bit is %x\n", RegB);

    if (RegB | 0)
    {
        RegB = RegB & ~ (1 << s[j]);
    }
    else
    {
        RegB;
    }
```

Before we continue, though, there are quite a few opportunities to simplify:

- variable `L` just complicates things for me; I'd rather just see `~K`
- `RegB | 0` is eqivalent to simply `RegB`
- the `else` block does nothing
- the `if` block can safely be executed unconditionally, in the sense that nothing will change if it is executed when the given condition is false.
- Although you have set `K = (1 << s[j])` and do not afterward change it, you later repeat yourself by using the expression `(1 << s[j])` instead of just saying `K`.
- the `printf()` may have some utility for debugging, but it slightly obscures the details of the computation

This equivalent code will be easier to reason about:

```
    K = (1 << s[j]);
    RegB = RegA & K;
    RegB = RegB & ~K;
```

And at that point the problem should be crystal clear: no matter what the value of `RegA` is, as long as `s[j]` is between 0 and 30,<sup>*</sup> you compute `RegB` by first masking off some of `RegA`'s bits, and then masking off the remaining ones.  Naturally, the result is always 0.

<sup>*</sup>Because `1` is a *signed* integer constant, if the implementation's `int`s are 32 bits wide, left-shifting by 31 places produces an out-of-range result.  As far as the standard is concerned, the resulting behavior is undefined.  It would be better to avoid this issue by using an unsigned constant, i.e. `1U`.

Comment: I performed your equivalent code. Still the execution of RegB = RegA & K; and RegB = RegB & ~K; not taking place. I set a breakpoint and verified it. When the breakpoint is currently at if (RegB | 0) the register values are as follows

i = 0x00000001
J = 0x00000000
K = 0x00000002
L = 0x00000000
RegA = 0x01001111
RegB = 0x00000000
S = 0x006ff700{0x00000001}

Comment: @vikash23, it's unclear what you think you've determined from running your code or my equivalent alternative in a debugger, but if you're running mine at all then it seems you've misunderstood my entire point.  I'm trying to tell you that **the result of the computation you have implemented is *always* zero**.  That the program in fact computes that result shows that the operations involved *are* being performed.  You have implemented a different computation than the one you were tasked with, and the computer is flawlessly executing what you told it to do.